# CakePHP easy way to use different values in select input

Tags: php, cakephp

I got a little "problem" with CakePHP.
My code is working fine, but I am looking for a way to shorten the code.

I have a model called "Document" and it "belongsTo" several "User"s.

- creator
- editor
- responsiblePerson

In my Controller I use the following code to load a list of all the available users:

```
$creators= $this->Document->Creator->find('list');
$editors= $this->Document->Editor->find('list');
$responsiblepersons= $this->Document->Responsibleperson->find('list');
$this->set(compact('creators','editors','responsiblepersons');
```

Now I can use this code in my views:

```
echo $this->Form->input($creator_id);
echo $this->Form->input($editor_id);
echo $this->Form->input($responsibleperson_id);
```

This is working fine, but is it really necessary to find all 3 lists?
In my controller $creators, $editors & $responsiblepersons contain all the same elements.
Overall one "Document" is connected to 6 different "User"s, so this is really bloating my code.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: are creator, editor and responsiblePerson aliases to the same model?

Comment: Yes, they are all User-models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they all are associated with the same table and model than just do:

```
$users = $this->Document->Creator->find('list');
```

And use the same list everywhere where you need the same list in the views.

Comment: Same table and model yes, but 3 different fields.
creator_id, editor_id and responsibleperson_id.
So I need something like this `$this->Form->input('creator_id',$users)`

Comment: Check the documentation. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html 2nd arg of input() is an options array. 'type' => 'select', 'options' => $list is needed for a select input.